# How to host multi-pages in phoneapplicationframe in wp8 like facebook 5 for wp8 app

Tags: windows-phone-8

How to implement a navigation bar like the facebook app for wp8
I want to implement a navigation bar for my wp8 app, it look like the facebook app for windows phone 8, Click on the left menu to slide profile pages ... or Swipe left to show profile page, swipe right to show friend.

My idea is host 3 pages (Profile Page, MainPage, FriendPage) on a phoneapplicationframe, when use click on the profile icon the Profile Page will be visible and the Mainpage will be margined to left ... , It is possible? How can i do it.

Any feedback will help me so much. Please help me, i'm stucked here.
Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've blogged about a possible solution for this, but I have to agree an `usercontrol` would be a better option!

http://depblog.weblogs.us/2013/07/30/facebook-like-settings-pane-with-gestures-windows-phone/

Answer (score 0):

I believe it was only one single page whose width is more than the screen's width. And the default view is achieved by setting the margin or other property which is for you to findout using trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

1. First, create a custom control/user control as design same as profile icon pressing profile page.
2. Then, drag it onto your main page. and set it margin properly how you want.
3. When you press the profile icon button. Then only you need to show it and collapse it when tapping screen.

Comment: Yes, thanks you. You help me get a new idea for this. You are right, i  should follow you idea.
Thanks